# Pull tables with PyRFC as external organisation

Tags: python, pyrfc

Our client has a SAP R/3 running and we need to pull tables out of this system to create insights and analytics. So does the client need to install Python and the PyRFC package or are we able to extract tables from our (M365) environment as long as they have the Netweaver RFC SDK?

Thank you very much for your help and have a good day!
Rudd